# How to generate unique element names or auto-increment element names with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there a way to auto-increment the element names of a Collection when marshalling to an XML using JAXB? I generate an XML using this code:

```
public void saveTestSettings(final String filename, final DefaultTestSettings t) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {

            final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath((paths.getTestSettingsPath() + filename));
            if (Files.notExists(path.getParent()))
                throw new Exception(path.getParent().toString() + " does not exist!!");
            final OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(path));
            final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DefaultTestSettings.class);
            final Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal(t, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (JAXBException | IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

```
   <defaultTestSettings>
    <groups>
        <instruments>
            <name>A200</name>
        </instruments>
        <name>A0</name>
       </groups>
    <groups>
        <instruments>
            <name>A300</name>
        </instruments>
        <instruments>
            <name>A400</name>
        </instruments>
        <name>A1</name>
       </groups>
    </defaultTestSettings>
```

I would like the `groups` and `instruments` to be automatically incremented, so that the result looks like this:

```
<defaultTestSettings>
    <groups1>
        <instruments1>
            <name>A200</name>
        </instruments1>
        <name>A0</name>
    </groups1>
    <groups2>
        <instruments1>
            <name>A300</name>
        </instruments1>
        <instruments2>
            <name>A400</name>
        </instruments2>
        <name>A1</name>
    </groups2>
</defaultTestSettings>
```

I am not too familiar with using XML schema, would that work?

Comment: A useful contract, but not with a list or array, nope, you dont have any control beyond specifying the element name for the entire element component.

Comment: I would recommend not having auto-incrementing element names.  Is there a reason you want to implement it this way?

Comment: I agree, but there is a dependency on other software which will parse the XML file. The elements have to be unique for it to be able to distinguish individual elements. Unfortunately, I have no control over that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are a couple of way's this use case could be handled:

## Option #1 - Using the Standard JAXB APIs

My answer below expands on the [excellent answer given by Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23966368/383861).  I have extended it to use an `XmlAdapter` to remove the logic from the `getElements()` method.

### Java Model

**DefaultSettings**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class DefaultSettings {

    private List<Groups> groups = new ArrayList<Groups>();

    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(GroupsAdapter.class)
    public List<Groups> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

}
```

**Groups**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

public class Groups {

    private List<Instruments> instruments = new ArrayList<Instruments>();

    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(InstrumentsAdapter.class)
    public List<Instruments> getInstruments() {
        return instruments;
    }

}
```

**Instruments**

```
public class Instruments {

}
```

### XmlAdapter

**GroupsAdapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class GroupsAdapter extends XmlAdapter<JAXBElement<Groups>, Groups> {

    private int counter = 1;
    private InstrumentsAdapter instrumentsAdapter = new InstrumentsAdapter();

    public InstrumentsAdapter getInstrumentsAdapter() {
        return instrumentsAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public Groups unmarshal(JAXBElement<Groups> v) throws Exception {
        return v.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<Groups> marshal(Groups v) throws Exception {
        instrumentsAdapter.resetCounter();
        return new JAXBElement<Groups>(new QName("groups" + counter++), Groups.class, v);
    }

}
```

**InstrumentsAdapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class InstrumentsAdapter extends XmlAdapter<JAXBElement<Instruments>, Instruments> {

    private int counter = 1;

    @Override
    public Instruments unmarshal(JAXBElement<Instruments> v) throws Exception {
        return v.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<Instruments> marshal(Instruments v) throws Exception {
        return new JAXBElement<Instruments>(new QName("instruments" + counter++), Instruments.class, v);
    }

    public void resetCounter() {
        counter = 1;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(DefaultSettings.class, Groups.class, Instruments.class);

        Groups groups1 = new Groups();
        groups1.getInstruments().add(new Instruments());
        groups1.getInstruments().add(new Instruments());

        Groups groups2 = new Groups();
        groups2.getInstruments().add(new Instruments());
        groups2.getInstruments().add(new Instruments());

        DefaultSettings ds = new DefaultSettings();
        ds.getGroups().add(groups1);
        ds.getGroups().add(groups2);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        GroupsAdapter groupsAdapter = new GroupsAdapter();
        marshaller.setAdapter(groupsAdapter);
        marshaller.setAdapter(groupsAdapter.getInstrumentsAdapter());
        marshaller.marshal(ds, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<defaultSettings>
    <groups1>
        <instruments1/>
        <instruments2/>
    </groups1>
    <groups2>
        <instruments1/>
        <instruments2/>
    </groups2>
</defaultSettings>
```

### Option #2 - Using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)'s `@XmlVariableNode` Extension

Below is a link to how this use case can be mapped using hte `@XmlVariableNode` extension that we added in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/mapping-bad-xml-enumerated-collection.html

Comment: I upvoted both answers, as they got me on the right track, but this detailed explanation was really helpful as it was simple and explicit. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [@XmlAnyElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html) annotation.
Simple example `groups` tag.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "defaultTestSettings")
@XmlSeeAlso(Group.class)
public class DefaultTestSettings
{
   private static int counter = 1;
   private static final String PROP = "group";

   List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

   @XmlAnyElement
   public List<JAXBElement<Group>> getElements()
   {
      final  List<JAXBElement<Group>> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
      for (final Group g : groups)
      {
         retVal.add(new JAXBElement(new QName(PROP + counter++), Group.class, g));
      }
      return retVal;
   }
}
```